# ContextMenu is not setted by DataTrigger, but it is displayed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, contextmenu

I use MVVM mode.

There are two ViewModels:
**ClientViewModel** and **DiskViewModel**, ClientViewModel has a collection `ObservableCollection<DiskViewModel>`.

I want to display their hierarchical relationship and do something via their `ContextMenu`. I set different `ContextMenu` via `TypeToBooleanConverter` in `DataTrigger` in `TreeViewItem` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding Converter={cvt:TypeToBooleanConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Type vm:ClientViewModel}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Client"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But there is a problem:

If I only set `ContextMenu` for **ClientViewModel** via above method, not set `ContextMenu` for **DiskViewModel**, it will be show "Client" if right-click on Disk `TreeViewItem`. But I never set it.

With a picture: this is not I need. I want to nothing if I right-click on Disk `TreeViewItem`.
[image]

Above scene is the simplest. Actually hierarchical relationship is that:

```
ClientList
|---Client
    |---DiskList
        |---Disk
            |---PartitionList
                |---Partition
```

Different types of item or one type time with different status has different ContextMenu. Enumerate all cases may be a hadr work.

I Need your help.

Code files:

```
// MainViewModel.cs
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication12.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ClientList = new ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel>();
            var disk = new DiskViewModel();
            disk.Name = "disk1";
            var client = new ClientViewModel();
            client.Name = "client1";
            client.DiskList.Add(disk);
            ClientList.Add(client);
        }

        #region ClientList
        public const string ClientListPropertyName = "ClientList";
        private ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel> _clientList;
        public ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel> ClientList
        {
            get
            {
                return _clientList;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_clientList == value)
                    return;

                _clientList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(ClientListPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion // ClientList
    }

    public class ClientViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ClientViewModel()
        {
            DiskList = new ObservableCollection<DiskViewModel>();
        }

        #region Name
        public const string NamePropertyName = "Name";
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_name == value)
                    return;

                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion // Name

        #region DiskList
        public const string DiskListPropertyName = "DiskList";
        private ObservableCollection<DiskViewModel> _diskList;
        public ObservableCollection<DiskViewModel> DiskList
        {
            get
            {
                return _diskList;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_diskList == value)
                    return;

                _diskList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(DiskListPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion // DiskList
    }

    public class DiskViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public DiskViewModel()
        {

        }

        #region Name
        public const string NamePropertyName = "Name";
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_name == value)
                    return;

                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion // Name
    }
}
```

.

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12.ViewModel"
        xmlns:cvt="clr-namespace:InfoCore.StreamerConsole.Converters"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=Main}">

    <Grid>
        <TreeView Background="AliceBlue" Margin="10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientList}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ClientViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding DiskList}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DiskViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>

            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding Converter={cvt:TypeToBooleanConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Type vm:ClientViewModel}}">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Client"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <!--<DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding Converter={cvt:TypeToBooleanConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Type vm:DiskViewModel}}">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Disk"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>-->
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.

```
// ToBooleanConverter.cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(TypeToBooleanConverter))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(Type), typeof(bool))]
public class TypeToBooleanConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static TypeToBooleanConverter _converter = null;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _converter ?? (_converter = new TypeToBooleanConverter());
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return Type.Equals(value.GetType(), parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: <DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding Converter={cvt:TypeToBooleanConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Type vm:ClientViewModel}}"> in this line what you are checking to be true ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Checking the DataContext of TreeViewItem if is type of ClientViewModel. Binding="{Binding}" is equivalent to Binding="{Binding Path=.}". here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seems too complicated. Prepare a base class and control tool tips through a base property?

Comment: @dytori Not necessarily. In this case, present some list whose hierarchical relationship like above via a TreeView control, and display a ContextMenu if right-click on Client object, but nothing if Disk object. I match type via the TypeToBooleanConverter.